# ImagePullBackOff local repository with Minikube

Tags: docker, kubernetes, kitematic

I'm trying to use minikube and kitematic for testing kubernetes on my local machine. However, kubernetes fail to pull image in my local repository (`ImagePullBackOff`).

I tried to solve it with this : [Can not pull docker image from private repo when using Minikube](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38748717/can-not-pull-docker-image-from-private-repo-when-using-minikube)

But I have no `/etc/init.d/docker`, I think it's because of kinematic ? (I am on OS X)

**EDIT :**

I installed https://github.com/docker/docker-registry, and

```
docker tag local-image-build localhost:5000/local-image-build

docker push localhost:5000/local-image-build
```

My kubernetes yaml contains :

```
spec:
  containers:
  - name: backend-nginx
    image: localhost:5000/local-image-build:latest
    imagePullPolicy: Always
```

But it's still not working...
Logs :

```
Error syncing pod, skipping: failed to "StartContainer" 
for "backend-nginx" with ErrImagePull: "Error while pulling image: 
Get http://127.0.0.1:5000/v1/repositories/local-image-build/images: 
dial tcp 127.0.0.1:5000: getsockopt: connection refused
```

**EDIT 2 :**

I don't know if I'm on the good path, but I find this :

http://kubernetes.io/docs/user-guide/images/

But I don't know what is my DOCKER_USER...

```
kubectl create secret docker-registry myregistrykey --docker-server=DOCKER_REGISTRY_SERVER --docker-username=DOCKER_USER --docker-password=DOCKER_PASSWORD --docker-email=DOCKER_EMAIL
```

**EDIT 3**

now I got on my pod :

```
Failed to pull image "local-image-build:latest": Error: image library/local-image-build not found
Error syncing pod, skipping: failed to "StartContainer" for "backend-nginx" with ErrImagePull: "Error: image library/local-image-build not found"
```

Help me I'm going crazy.

**EDIT 4**

```
Error syncing pod, skipping: failed to "StartContainer" for "backend-nginx" with ErrImagePull: "Error response from daemon: Get https://192.168.99.101:5000/v1/_ping: tls: oversized record received with length 20527"
```

I added :

```
EXTRA_ARGS='
    --label provider=virtualbox
    --insecure-registry=192.168.99.101:5000
```

to my docker config, but it's still don't work, the same message....

By the way, I changed my yaml :

```
 spec:
      containers:
      - name: backend-nginx
        image: 192.168.99.101:5000/local-image-build:latest
        imagePullPolicy: Always
```

And I run my registry like that :

```
docker run -d -p 5000:5000 --restart=always --name myregistry registry:2
```

Comment: Did you actually run the registry? The command to do it is `docker run -d -p 5000:5000 --name registry registry:2`

Comment: What about using the docker registry in the minikube registry?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I think I solved by doing

```
minikube start --vm-driver="virtualbox" --insecure-registry="$REG_IP":80
```

instead of just

```
minikube start
```

$REG_IP is :

```
REG_IP=docker-machine ip registry
```

[Source](http://thenewstack.io/tutorial-configuring-ultimate-development-environment-kubernetes/)

Comment: what is $REG_IP?

Comment: REG_IP=`docker-machine ip registry`

Comment: `docker-machine` is now superseded / deprecated https://docs.docker.com/machine/overview/

Comment: Any solution for 2022? Since docker-machine is deprecated.

Answer (score 57):

Use the minikube docker registry instead of your local docker

https://kubernetes.io/docs/tutorials/stateless-application/hello-minikube/#create-a-docker-container-image

### Set docker to point to minikube

`eval $(minikube docker-env)`

### Push to minikube docker

`docker build -t hello-node:v1 .`

### Set your deployment to not pull IfNotPresent

K8S default is set to "Always"
Change to "IfNotPresent"

`imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent`

[Related Issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40144138/pull-a-local-image-to-run-a-pod-in-kubernetes)

Comment: thanks, quick and easy(in my view, correct solution for the stated problem).
btw, first step (eval) is not required if minikube is started with "--vm-driver=none".

Comment: `eval $(minikube docker-env)` this didn't work for me instead `eval $(minikube -p minikube docker-env)` worked for me

Answer (score 5):

If you're using `--vm-driver=none`, you'll need to set [imagePullPolicy](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/overview/#container-images) to `Never`.

> imagePullPolicy: Never: the image is assumed to exist locally. No
> attempt is made to pull the image.

Answer (score 3):

Check this great article: [How to Run Locally Built Docker Images in Kubernetes](https://medium.com/swlh/how-to-run-locally-built-docker-images-in-kubernetes-b28fbc32cc1d)

### My Environment

- OS: Debian
- Version: 11 (Bullseye)
- Minikube: v1.24.0
- Kubectl: v1.22.4
- Docker: 20.10.5+dfsg1

It covers all wrong image stages and workarounds.

**Stages**

##### ErrImagePull

Edit `deployment.yaml` and add `imagePullPolicy: Never`:

```yaml
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: my-local-deployment
spec:
  template:
    metadata:
      name: my-pod
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: my-container
        image: my-local-image    # The one built and tagged locally
        imagePullPolicy: Never   # So it doesn't pull the image from remote registry
```

##### ErrImageNeverPull

Run: `eval $(minikube -p minikube docker-env)`

that outputs environment variables needed to point the local Docker daemon to the minikube internal Docker registry

##### Finally

Rebuild the image, to install it in minikube registry:

`docker build . -t my-image`

Comment: one question about "eval $(minikube -p minikube docker-env)" does that means your docker command will be related always to minikube machine ? I mean I would like to keep using docker out of the minikube context for other projects etc...

Answer (score 3):

As per the kubernetes documentation here: https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/containers/images/#imagepullpolicy-defaulting

If you use the latest tag for deployment then it will try to pull image.
I was able to deploy service with v1 tag after following steps on WSL-2

1. eval $(minikube -p minikube docker-env)
2. minikube start
3. docker build --tag=my-service:v1 .
4. kubectl create deployment my-service --image=my-service:v1
5. kubectl expose pod "my-service" --type=NodePort --port=8080
6. minikube service my-serivce

Answer (score 3):

If you are using minikube in **Windows**.

I solved it by just building my image in minikube cluster as below because I just wanted to test it.

Go to your directory where you want to build an image.

Try below command to build your images in minikube on your local

> **minikube image build -t your_image_name:tag .**

Then you can give reference to this **images** with **tag** in your deployment.yaml or pods.yaml

Answer (score 2):

in my case, I had to do the following steps.

$ eval $(minikube docker-env)

$ minikube config set driver virtualbox

$ minikube start

Answer (score 1):

I tested in CentOS7 and works for me.

First load image into minikube first by using:
`minikube image load test/kubia`

Check images list from minikube: `minikube image ls`

Then do not pull from remote by config yaml file

```
apiVersion: v1               
kind: Pod                    
metadata:
  name: kubia-manual         
spec:
  containers:
  - image: test/kubia
    name: kubia
    # This will use local image from minikube image list
    imagePullPolicy: Never
    ports:
    - containerPort: 8080
      protocol: TCP
```

```
NAME           READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
kubia-manual   1/1     Running   0          7s
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding --insecure-registry="$REG_IP":80 does not seem to work for me.

I have to use wlredeye's answer at 
[Can not pull docker image from private repo when using Minikube](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38748717/can-not-pull-docker-image-from-private-repo-when-using-minikube)
to get it working:

For an http registry this steps works for me:

1. minikube ssh
2. edit /var/lib/boot2docker/profile and add to $EXTRA_ARGS 
   `--insecure-registry 192.168.99.1(your local machine's IP):5000`
3. restart the docker daemon 
   `sudo /etc/init.d/docker restart`
4. Verify you can access the docker registry
   `curl -s -S http://192.168.99.1/v2/_catalog`

This is minikube version: v0.14.0

Comment: Two questions about this one. By "local machine's IP" you mean "the IP of the registry" right? Also how *exactly* are you "adding to" that variable.

Comment: I added the line: EXTRA_ARGS --insecure-registry 192.168.99.1:5000, but I get an error with $ sudo /etc/init.d/docker restart
sudo: /etc/init.d/docker: command not found

Answer (score 0):

First you need to start a local registry, seems you have done it.

`docker run -d -p 5000:5000 --restart=always --name myregistry registry:2`

You can check your minikube IP by `ifconfig`

There should be output (after minikube start using virtualbox as VMdriver) looks like:

`vboxnet0  Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 0a:00:27:00:00:00

          inet addr:192.168.99.1  Bcast:192.168.99.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::800:27ff:fe00:0/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:515 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:86256 (86.2 KB)`

Using

`minikube start --insecure-registry=192.168.99.1:5000`

You can actually check whether you can pull your own images simply by (within minikube)

`docker pull 192.168.99.1:5000/your_own_repo/your_own_images`

Hope this might help.

Answer (score 0):

**in Mac** I have problem with dns-resolving in minikube, as /etc/resolv.conf was configured with my mac ip. I didn't have installed dns server locally, so minikube couldn't resolve anything.

I solved this with install locally dns-server

```
brew install dnsmasq
sudo brew services start dnsmasq
```

Answer (score 0):

in Mac I had docker client installed so I had to do

```
minikube config set driver docker
minikube start
```

Answer (score 0):

#### Start minikube

```sh
minikube start --insecure-registry "10.0.0.0/24,192.168.39.0/24"
minikube addons enable registry
```

#### Find minikube IP

```sh
minikube ip
```

#### Setup docker/insecure-registry

```json
# edit /etc/docker/daemon.json
{
  ...
  "insecure-registries": [ "your-minikube-ip:5000" ]
  ...
}
```

#### Push your image

```sh
docker build --tag $(minikube ip):5000/local-image-build:latest
docker push $(minikube ip):5000/local-image-build:latest
```

Enjoy it.

See:
https://minikube.sigs.k8s.io/docs/handbook/pushing/#4-pushing-to-an-in-cluster-using-registry-addon

Answer (score 0):

in my case(running minikube on M1), adding `imagePullPolicy: Never` fixed the issue