# Pull a local image to run a pod in Kubernetes

Tags: docker, kubernetes

I have the following image created by a Dockerfile:

```
REPOSITORY   TAG      IMAGE ID       CREATED       SIZE 
ruby/lab     latest   f1903b1508cb   2 hours ago   729.6 MB
```

And I have my following YAML file:

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: ruby-deployment
spec:
  replicas: 2
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: ruby
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: ruby-app
        image: ruby/lab
        imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
        ports:
        - containerPort: 4567
```

When I create the deployment I got the following info in the pods:

```
ruby-deployment-3830038651-sa4ii   0/1       ImagePullBackOff   0          7m
ruby-deployment-3830038651-u1tvc   0/1       ImagePullBackOff   0          7m
```

And the error `Failed to pull image "ruby/lab:latest": Error: image ruby/lab not found` from below:

```
 8m            2m              6       {kubelet minikube}      spec.containers{ruby}   Normal          Pulling         pulling image "ruby/lab:latest"
 8m            2m              6       {kubelet minikube}      spec.containers{ruby}   Warning         Failed          Failed to pull image "ruby/lab:latest": Error: image ruby/lab not found
 8m            2m              6       {kubelet minikube}                              Warning         FailedSync      Error syncing pod, skipping: failed to "StartContainer" for "ruby" with ErrImagePull: "Error: image ruby/lab not found"
```

Is really necessary to have registry in docker for this? I just want to make test locally and pass my code/repo to a friend for testing purposes

Thanks

Answer (score 112, accepted):

You can point your docker client to the VM's docker daemon by running

```
eval $(minikube docker-env)
```

Then you can build your image normally and create your kubernetes resources normally using kubectl.  Make sure that you have

```
imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
```

in your YAML or JSON specs.

Additionally, there is a flag to pass in insecure registries to the minikube VM.  However, this must be specified the first time you create the machine.

```
minikube start --insecure-registry
```

You may also want to read this when using a private registry
http://kubernetes.io/docs/user-guide/images/

Comment: @CPB can you mark this as the answer if it solved your issue please?

Comment: that worked for me without `minikube start --insecure-registry`. It was not clear for me where to put imagePullPolicy, but I found out. That should be in your deployment.yaml `.spec.template.containers.imagePullPolicy`

Comment: What if I don't use minikube but want to upload the image to a remote cluster?
Can kubectl upload the image?

Comment: No @PeterDotchev, you will have to use the docker CLI to do so. And you'll have to have a docker image registry configured, since one is not included in a vanilla kubernetes cluster.

Comment: @MattRickard : I don't use minikube, I use kubectl, kubernetes cluster, I don't have a docker image registry. Can I use local image for deployment ?

Comment: ANy idea what to pass, flag needs an argument: --insecure-registry

Comment: `minikube start --insecure-registry true`

Comment: I use ContainerD and I had to remove "imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent" completely and then it respected that the image was already there. I did this just as a last resort for grins and giggles just to see if it would work and lo and behold, it did. I run K8s in an Air-gapped configuration so I have to import the images into the Worker Nodes.

Comment: To answer the original question more directly, especially if Joe can't (or won't) push the image to a repo to which he and his friend have access, he can commit container back to an image (if there's changes in the container that aren't in his image via "docker commit -p CONTAINER_ID NEWNAME"), then save the image to a tarball (via "docker save -o TARBALLNAME.tar IMAGENAME").  He can then send the tarball to his friend who can load it into his Docker (via "docker load --input TARBALLNAME.tar").

Comment: Joe didn't mention which K8S flavor he uses, but (by default) Minikube uses it's own internal instance of Docker. You can access Minikube's internal Docker instance by first connecting to the Minikube container (via "minikube ssh") then running your Docker commands.

Comment: i am running minikube but the command eval $(minikube docker-env) is not working for me

Answer (score 40):

AFAIR minikube runs in a VM hence it will not see the images you've built locally on a host machine, but... as stated in https://github.com/kubernetes/minikube/blob/master/docs/reusing_the_docker_daemon.md you can use `eval $(minikube docker-env)` to actually utilise docker daemon running on minikube, and henceforth build your image on the minikubes docker and thus expect it to be available to the minikubes k8s engine without pulling from external registry

Comment: I don't use minikube, I use kubectl, kubernetes. How can I fix this ?

Comment: I did this, but it still can't find the local image.

Comment: If you're publishing your image using SBT and SBT is running as an existing daemon process that was spawned in another process space then it would not inherit the environment defined by `minikube docker-env`

Answer (score 9):

To use an image without uploading it, you can follow these steps:
It is important that you be in same shell since you are setting environment variables!

1. Set the environment variables with eval $(minikube docker-env)
2. Build the image (eg docker build -t my-image .)
3. Set the image in the pod spec like the build tag (eg my-image)
4. Set the imagePullPolicy to Never, otherwise, Kubernetes will try to download the image.

Answer (score 3):

I ran in a similar issue with minikube v1.9.2, Kubernetes v1.18.0, Docker 19.03.2 on Centos 8.1.1911. All in a single machine used for develop, I chosen for a local insecure docker registry.

The following steps were useful for me to share the local insecure docker registry with local kubernetes/minikube env and to allow kube nodes (and also minikube) to reach Internet:

1. Disable the firewalld in order to make DNS resolution work inside
   Docker containers with (reboot required):
   `systemctl disable firewalld`
   Otherwise during minikube startup it is prompted the following:
   *VM may be unable to resolve external DNS records

   VM is unable to access k8s.gcr.io, you may need to configure a proxy or set --image-repository.*
   I wasted several days on this.
2. Retrieve the IP of the network interface created and used
   by docker, in my case I have `docker0` interface name with IP `172.17.0.1`. The local insecure registry will be exposed to minikube on this IP.
3. Configure Docker to read/write from insecure registry by adding the
   following in `/etc/docker/daemon.json`:
   `{"insecure-registries" : ["172.17.0.1:5000"]}`
4. Restart Docker:
   `systemctl restart docker.service`
5. Run minikube with
   `minikube start --insecure-registry="172.17.0.1:5000"`
   (if already running or yet started, run `minikube delete` before to start)
6. Build, tag and push your application in the local insecure registry:
   `docker build -t mydemo/demo .`
   `docker tag mydemo/demo 172.17.0.1:5000/myminikubedemo`
   `docker push 172.17.0.1:5000/myminikubedemo`
7. Now when you create the deployment.yaml descriptor for your application put the correct
   image path and then apply:
   `kubectl create deployment mydemo --image=172.17.0.1:5000/myminikubedemo --dry-run=client -o=yaml > deployment.yaml`
   `kubectl apply -f deployment.yaml`

Answer (score 1):

Here's an alternative solution to do it manually:

1 - make a .tar file of the respective docker image:

```
docker save -o nginx.tar nginx:1.19.0-alpine
```

2 - SSH to the minikube VM:

```
minikube ssh
```

3 - load the docker image:

```
docker load -i /path/to/nginx.tar
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the *minikube* VM can not pull the images even though they are stored locally and the `imagePullPolicy` is set to `Never`.

My workaround solution is creating a local docker repository and pushing these images to that repository. Then, specify the image as follow: `localhost:5000/image/name`. Sources: https://minikube.sigs.k8s.io/docs/handbook/registry/#docker-on-macos

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I have setup k8s cluster with kubeadm.
so, if you want to use local image to run pod do below things.

If you have docker image, create tar file of image by using below command.

```
docker save <image-name> -o <filename.tar>
```

If you have containerd image, create tar file of image by using below command.

```
ctr image export <output-filename> <image-name>
```

After transferring the standalone archives to the other systems (using whatever means you prefer; I used scp), then load (or import) the images into containerd with this command:

```
ctr -n=k8s.io images import <filename-from-previous-step>
```

Verify that the image(s) are present and recognized by containerd using

```
ctr -n=k8s.io image ls
```

Answer (score 0):

Contributing to the answer provided by Radek 'Goblin' Pieczonka and Kross with the intention of helping some windows users:

Minikube runs in a docker. Hence it cannot access the images you've built locally on a host machine. So, you will have to point your host's shell to minikube's docker-daemon and build the docker image of the application, in order to make it available to the minikube's kubernetes engine without pulling from external registry.

How to switch to the docker daemon of Minikube?
If you are on Linux, execute this command `eval $(minikube docker-env)`.

If you are using windows, execute this command `minikube docker-env`. This will print some lines similar to what is shown below:

```
SET DOCKER_TLS_VERIFY=1
SET DOCKER_HOST=tcp://127.0.0.1:56995
SET DOCKER_CERT_PATH=C:\Users\JohnDoe\.minikube\certs
SET MINIKUBE_ACTIVE_DOCKERD=minikube
REM To point your shell to minikube's docker-daemon, run:
REM @FOR /f "tokens=*" %i IN ('minikube -p minikube docker-env --shell cmd') DO @%i
```

The REM lines are comments that provide additional information. According to the REM lines above, executing `@FOR /f "tokens=*" %i IN ('minikube -p minikube docker-env --shell cmd') DO @%i` will configure the shell to point to Minikube's Docker daemon.

Answer (score -3):

docker pull , pulls all images manually in every node
or 
run a DaemonSet to pull all images