# Kubernetes deployment with Docker image

Tags: docker, kubernetes, minikube

I am running Kubernetes (Minikube) on my local Mac.

I am trying to setup a deployment with Docker image and getting the below error. But, the hello-world deployment with the Docker image "gcr.io/google-samples/node-hello:1.0" works as expected.

I am able to pull the image from a console on my local machine. Am I missing any setting here?

> "Failed to pull image
> "docker.XYZ.com/dpace/dev/docker-service": rpc error:
> code = Unknown desc = Error response from daemon: Get
> https:/docker.XYZ.com/v2/: dial tcp: lookup
> docker.XYZ.com on 10.0.2.3:53: read udp
> 10.0.2.15:59292->10.0.2.3:53: i/o timeout"

I am able to pull the image using `docker pull docker.XYZ.com/dpace/dev/docker-service` in my local machine without any auth issue. It doesn't need auth for pulling images.

I tried logging into Minikube VM and Docker images returns the following.

> $ docker images REPOSITORY                                    TAG
> IMAGE ID            CREATED             SIZE
> k8s.gcr.io/kubernetes-dashboard-amd64         v1.8.1
> e94d2f21bc0c        3 months ago        121MB
> gcr.io/google-containers/kube-addon-manager   v6.5
> d166ffa9201a        4 months ago        79.5MB
> gcr.io/k8s-minikube/storage-provisioner       v1.8.0
> 4689081edb10        4 months ago        80.8MB
> gcr.io/k8s-minikube/storage-provisioner       v1.8.1
> 4689081edb10        4 months ago        80.8MB
> k8s.gcr.io/k8s-dns-sidecar-amd64              1.14.5
> fed89e8b4248        5 months ago        41.8MB
> k8s.gcr.io/k8s-dns-kube-dns-amd64             1.14.5
> 512cd7425a73        5 months ago        49.4MB
> k8s.gcr.io/k8s-dns-dnsmasq-nanny-amd64        1.14.5
> 459944ce8cc4        5 months ago        41.4MB k8s.gcr.io/echoserver
> 1.4                 a90209bb39e3        21 months ago       140MB gcr.io/google_containers/pause-amd64          3.0
> 99e59f495ffa        22 months ago       747kB k8s.gcr.io/pause-amd64
> 3.0                 99e59f495ffa        22 months ago       747kB gcr.io/google-samples/node-hello              1.0
> 4c7ea8709739        23 months ago       644MB

Though the images are there, when I try to pull the existing image, it fails with the below error.

> $ docker pull gcr.io/google-samples/node-hello:1.0 Error response from
> daemon: Get https://gcr.io/v2/: dial tcp: lookup gcr.io on
> 10.0.2.3:53: read udp 10.0.2.15:44023->10.0.2.3:53: i/o timeout

When I try "docker login docker.XYZ.com", it prompts me to enter the credential. It throws the below error after entering the password. Same error while trying to pull the image also.

> "Error response from daemon: Get https://docker.XYZ.com/v2/: dial tcp:
> lookup docker.XYZ.com on 10.0.2.3:53: read udp
> 10.0.2.15:41849->10.0.2.3:53: i/o timeout"
>
> The command "curl google.com" also not working.  "Could not resolve
> host: google.com"

Any setting to be done inside Minikube VM. I use VirtualBox.

Comment: Does [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40144138/pull-a-local-image-to-run-a-pod-in-kubernetes) help?

Comment: You're likely missing the required authentication/docker login credentials to pull that image. Double check if the image you're trying use is public. Then check that the registry you're trying to hit is accessible from inside the minkube virtual machine.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like DNS in your minikube is broken, that's why you cannot pull anything.

Here is an [Issue on Github](https://github.com/kubernetes/minikube/issues/2302) with the similar problem.

Try to update your minikube and your hypervisor (in most of cases it is Virtualbox) to the last version (check [here](https://github.com/kubernetes/minikube/releases)) and recreate a cluster, it should help.