# Deploy inhouse docker image in Kubernetes cluster

Tags: docker, kubernetes, kubeadm

I try to deploy one docker image that I build and is not on a public or private registry.

I use the `imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent` for the Kubernetes deployment.

I use kubeadm v1.12 the error:

```
Normal   Scheduled       35s                default-scheduler       Successfully assigned default/test-777dd9bc96-chgc7 to ip-10-0-1-154
Normal   SandboxChanged  32s                kubelet, ip-10-0-1-154  Pod sandbox changed, it will be killed and re-created.
Normal   BackOff         30s (x3 over 31s)  kubelet, ip-10-0-1-154  Back-off pulling image "test_kube"
Warning  Failed          30s (x3 over 31s)  kubelet, ip-10-0-1-154  Error: ImagePullBackOff
Normal   Pulling         15s (x2 over 34s)  kubelet, ip-10-0-1-154  pulling image "test"
Warning  Failed          13s (x2 over 33s)  kubelet, ip-10-0-1-154  Failed to pull image "test": rpc error: code = Unknown desc = Error response from daemon: pull access denied for test_kube, repository does not exist or may require 'docker login'
Warning  Failed          13s (x2 over 33s)  kubelet, ip-10-0-1-154  Error: ErrImagePull
```

My deployment file:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1beta1
kind: Deployment
vmetadata:
  name: test-kube
spec:
  template:
    metadata:
  labels:
    app: test
spec:
  containers:
  - name: test
    image: test
    imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
    ports:
    - containerPort: 3000
    env:
    - name: SECRET-KUBE
      valueFrom:
        secretKeyRef:
          name: secret-test
          key: username
```

> docker images]

```
REPOSITORY  TAG
test   latest 
test   test
```

In the deployment file i tried with

> image: test  and with image: test:test

The same error:

> Error: ErrImagePull

Comment: Check if your docker image is build with image tag" test_kube" using docker images. If not then change the docker image tag to test_kube

Comment: Using the right credentials? Did you push the image with the same credentials?

Comment: I try to deploy one docker image that I build and is not on a public or private registry.

Comment: @PrafullLadha i tried, the same problem thanks anyway :)

Answer (score 1):

- create a secret based on docker registry user with pull/push rights
- use it as imagePullSecret

OR

- pre-pull the image on the deployment node

**Details of creating secret and usage:**

A Kubernetes cluster uses the Secret of docker-registry type to authenticate with a container registry to pull a private image.

Create this Secret, naming it regcred:

```
kubectl create secret docker-registry regcred --docker-server=<your-registry-server> --docker-username=<your-name> --docker-password=<your-pword> --docker-email=<your-email>
```

where:

```
<your-registry-server> is your Private Docker Registry FQDN. (https://index.docker.io/v1/ for DockerHub)
<your-name> is your Docker username.
<your-pword> is your Docker password.
<your-email> is your Docker email.
```

Then create a pod that uses that secret:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: private-reg
spec:
  containers:
  - name: private-reg-container
    image: <your-private-image>
  imagePullSecrets:
  - name: regcred
```

For the local image use case please see this post:

[Pull a local image to run a pod in Kubernetes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40144138/pull-a-local-image-to-run-a-pod-in-kubernetes)

Comment: I build the image on the deployment node, is on the docker images, but nothing. 
I will try the first you said. 
Create docker private registry, pull and add the credential in kubernetes. Thanks :)

Comment: if the image is already on the node , it should work , check the path of image

Comment: @cdemet answer updated , please see that post to use local image

Comment: @IjazAhmadKhan original question is about kubeadm, your linked post is about minikube.

Answer (score 1):

You should have a docker private registry on the master node of the kubernetes cluster so that if the pod is deployed on a node to pull the image from there. You can find the steps to create a Kubernetes cluster with docker private registry at: [Kubernetes cluster with docker private registry](http://dradoaica.blogspot.com/2019/01/kubernetes-cluster-with-docker-private.html)

6. Creating a docker private registry on master node

```
# Set basic auth.
rm -f /auth/*
mkdir -p /auth
docker run --entrypoint htpasswd registry:2 -Bbn test test > /auth/htpasswd

docker rm registry -f
```

```
# Set certificates auth.
rm -f /certs/*
mkdir -p /certs
openssl genrsa 1024 > /certs/registrykey.pem
chmod 400 /certs/registrykey.pem
openssl req -new -x509 -nodes -sha1 -days 365 -key /certs/registrykey.pem  -out /certs/registry.pem  -subj "/C=/ST=/L=/O=/OU=/CN=registry.com" > /dev/null 2>&1
docker run -d -e REGISTRY_HTTP_ADDR=0.0.0.0:5000 -p 5000:5000 --restart=always --name registry -v `pwd`/auth:/auth -e "REGISTRY_AUTH=htpasswd" -e "REGISTRY_AUTH_HTPASSWD_REALM=Registry Realm" -e REGISTRY_AUTH_HTPASSWD_PATH=/auth/htpasswd -v `pwd`/certs:/certs -e REGISTRY_HTTP_TLS_CERTIFICATE=/certs/registry.pem -e REGISTRY_HTTP_TLS_KEY=/certs/registrykey.pem registry:2

# Create secret to be used in "imagePullSecrets" section of a pod
kubectl create secret docker-registry regsecret --docker-server=192.168.147.3:5000 --docker-username=test --docker-password=test --namespace=kube-system

# Push image in private registry.
docker tag test-image:latest 192.168.147.3:5000/test-image
docker push 192.168.147.3:5000/test-image
```

7. YAML example for pod with image from private registry

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: test-site
  labels:
    app: web
spec:
  containers:
    - name: test
  image: 192.168.147.3:5000/test-image:latest
    ports:
      - containerPort: 8000
  imagePullPolicy: Always
    imagePullSecrets:
      - name: regsecret
```