# ECR ImagePullBackOff

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ecr

I created a docker image that works, I pushed it in ECR, I tried to pull it to test it. 
I've succeeded to pull it => no error so far. But while  applying (on minikube) my deployment, I'm getting an ImagePullBackOff.
Here the code of my deployment file where I call my image (that I pulled) :

```
spec:
  containers:
  - name: mysql-cont
    image: XXXXXXXXXXX.dkr.ecr.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/<MY_REPO>:<MY-IMAGE>
    env:
```

Comment: This may help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38979231/imagepullbackoff-local-repository-with-minikube